# Highlight Selected Tab in ASP.Net Menu

Tags: asp.net, css

I am trying to hightlight with different color the selected tab in ASP.NET menu.  It seems simple to do this but first I am not able to make it to work, and second I cannot find a good working example so far.

**ASP/HTML**

```
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="False"
                    IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ReadMe.aspx" Text="Read Me" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Summary.aspx" Text="Summary" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Detail.aspx" Text="Detail" />
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color:#3a4f63;
    width:100%;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;

}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;

    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be [a duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7067944/1211329) But there is an answer which you might want to refer to.

Comment: another possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053337/asp-net-4-highlight-menu-item-for-current-page

Comment: I posted a working solution..check it out..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7068011/1085891) to [ASP.NET: Highlight menu item of current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067944/asp-net-highlight-menu-item-of-current-page) should provide the solution you're after.

Basically, you'll need to use the [Menu.StaticSelectedStyle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.staticselectedstyle.aspx). There's an example in the answer link above and in the documentation.

**Example Snippet**

```
<asp:menu [...]>
        <staticselectedstyle backcolor="LightBlue"
          borderstyle="Solid"
          bordercolor="Black"
          borderwidth="1"/>

        [...]
</asp:menu>
```

Also, you will need to remove the `menu` [attribute `IncludeStyleBlock="false"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.includestyleblock.aspx) as it " indicates whether ASP.NET should render a block of cascading style sheet (CSS) definitions for the styles that are used in the menu."

Other helpful links:

- [asp:MenuItem / CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390113/aspmenuitem-css)
- [StaticMenuItemStyle vs. StaticSelectedStyle - Does one overwrite the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676334/staticmenuitemstyle-vs-staticselectedstyle-does-one-overwrite-the-other)

Answer (score 5):

**This is a Working solution:**
**Script**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

   $(function () {
        // this will get the full URL at the address bar
        var url = window.location.href;

        // passes on every "a" tag 
        $("#cssmenu a").each(function () {
            // checks if its the same on the address bar
            if (url == (this.href)) {
                $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
            }
        });
        $("#header a").each(function () {
            // checks if its the same on the address bar
            if (url == (this.href)) {
                $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

**Markup**

**List items with div `id ="cssmenu"`**

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="../Admin/dashboard.aspx"><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="../Admin/Report.aspx"><span>Reports</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="../Admin/Shop.aspx"><span>Shop</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="../Admin/system.aspx"><span>System</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**StyleSheet**

```
#cssmenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 33px;
    font-size: .6em;
    background: url(images/bg.png) repeat-x top left;
    font-family: Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#cssmenu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#cssmenu li a {
    float: left;
    color: #A79787;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 9px 15px 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#cssmenu li a:hover,
#cssmenu .active {
    color: #fff;
    background: url(images/bg.png) repeat-x top left;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu .active a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#cssmenu ul { background-color: #629600 }
#cssmenu li a:hover,
#cssmenu li.active { background-color: #7AB900 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the Selected MenuItem Manually

```
NavigationMenu.Items(i).Selected = True
```

I've created a function to make highlighting easier.

```
SelectMenuByValue("Value2", NavigationMenu)
```

It takes the Value of the MenuItem and the Menu control instance as Parameters.

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server">
<Items>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Parent1" Value="ParentValue">
        <asp:MenuItem Text="SubMenu1" Value="Value1" NavigateUrl="~/Page1.aspx" />
        <asp:MenuItem Text="SubMenu2" Value="Value2" NavigateUrl="~/Page2.aspx" />
        <asp:MenuItem Text="SubMenu3" Value="Value3" NavigateUrl="~/Page3.aspx" />
    </asp:MenuItem>
</Items>
```

Code behind:

```
Public Sub SelectMenuByValue(ByVal sValue As String, ByVal NavigationMenu As Menu)
Dim iMenuCount As Integer = NavigationMenu.Items.Count - 1
For i As Integer = 0 To iMenuCount
    Dim menuItem As MenuItem = NavigationMenu.Items(i)
    If menuItem.Value = sValue Then
        If menuItem.Enabled AndAlso menuItem.Selectable Then menuItem.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
    If CheckSelectSubMenu(menuItem, sValue) Then Exit For
Next
End Sub

Private Function CheckSelectSubMenu(ByVal menuItem As MenuItem, ByVal sValue As String) As Boolean
    CheckSelectSubMenu = False
    Dim iMenuCount As Integer = menuItem.ChildItems.Count - 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To iMenuCount
        Dim subMenuItem As MenuItem = menuItem.ChildItems(i)
        If subMenuItem.Value = sValue Then
            CheckSelectSubMenu = True
            If subMenuItem.Enabled AndAlso subMenuItem.Selectable Then subMenuItem.Selected = True
            Exit For
        End If
        If CheckSelectSubMenu(subMenuItem, sValue) Then
            CheckSelectSubMenu = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**reference: from the forum [ASP.NET 4 : Highlight menu item for current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053337/asp-net-4-highlight-menu-item-for-current-page)**

Comment: I think it would be better if someone will downvote an answer/question atleast they will leave a comment

Comment: I know, but usually downvoters wont comment unless if it's the mods.